# Angularjs multiple instances of app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was wonder if it is possible to run same app on two separate browser and get updates from one to other?

let's say I have app running on chrome: http://127.0.0.1:8000/#
and same open in Firefox or other incognito chrome tab, when any of opened session updates something I want to get that update/alert on other session.
Any direction would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You should look at the server-side, not the client side.

Comment: so without server side it won't be possible?

Comment: More specifically, if you want the updates to happen instantaneously (i.e. without a page reload), you'll probably need to implement WebSockets on your server, or something along those lines. See http://socket.io/ (well, when it comes back up - seems to be down for me right now).

Comment: still you are saying required to have server-side to notify other sessions, on client side, is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: ok guys, let's say I have created localhost websocket, how would i do it now?

Comment: ok, I have managed to solve the issue, with websocket and app, running 2 webservers locally.

Answer (score 0):

I have created 2 webserver for this purpose:

one runs web-socket.
other app.

websocket example nodejs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var WebSocketServer = require("ws").Server;
var http = require("http");
var express = require("express");
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

var app = express();
    app.use(express.static(__dirname+ "/../"));
    app.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
       console.log('receiving get request');
    });
    app.post('/test', function(req, res, next) {
       console.log('receiving post request');
    });
    app.listen(80);

    //console.log("app listening on %d ", 80);

var server = http.createServer(app);
    server.listen(port);

console.log("http server listening on %d", port);


var userId;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({server: server});
    wss.on("connection", function (ws) {

    console.info("websocket connection open");

    var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    userId = timestamp;

    ws.send(JSON.stringify({msgType:"onOpenConnection", msg:{connectionId:timestamp}}));


    ws.on("message", function (data, flags) {
        console.log("websocket received a message");
        var clientMsg = data;
        wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
            client.send(clientMsg);
        });        
    });

    ws.on("close", function () {
        console.log("websocket connection close");
    });
});
console.log("websocket server created");
```

angularjs part:

```
.run(function ($rootScope) {
        if ("WebSocket" in window)
            {
               console.log("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");
               $rootScope.updated = false;
               // Let us open a web socket
               socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5000", "echo-protocol");
               socket.addEventListener("open", function(event) {
                  console.log( "Connected" );
                });

                // Display messages received from the server
                socket.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
                  console.log( "Server Says: " + event.data );

                  if (!$rootScope.updated)
                    if (event.data == "updated list") {
                      //here can passdata or update data
                      alert("Please refresh the page, new data should be available!");
                    }
                });

                // Display any errors that occur
                socket.addEventListener("error", function(event) {
                  console.log( "Error: " + event );
                });

                socket.addEventListener("close", function(event) {
                  console.log("Not Connected");
                });
            }

            else
            {
               // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
               alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
            }
    })
```

then run "node websocket.js"
and app "http-server -o"